# How can I fix the alignment issue in my android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alignment

I have created a login page with :
1 small image,
2 text boxes,
1 button
but I want them to align in all types of devices like when I tried on my device and it looks fine but not for the other devices that are bigger-smaller in screen-sizes

Thanks in advance

Here is the code :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:background="@color/blend"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagelogo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="294dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/User_name"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="147dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="227dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/Pass_word"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
    android:ems="13"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/login" />
```

and the output :
[Design + Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDqM5.png)

So i want all my things at same place in every type of devices

Comment: So what is the distance unit you are using?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SOF! Please put code you've tried

Comment: And what kind of layout are you using?

Comment: I'm using relative layout

Comment: Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719449/scale-imageview-to-look-the-same-on-phone-and-tablet/48719554#48719554 @DevarshBhatt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498646/handling-all-screen-sizes-android/52660036#52660036

Comment: Thanks to all of you who helped me. I have solved this question so no worries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below into your project level Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
```

Usage : In code wherever you are specifying dimensions like **10dp** change it to **@dimen/_10sdp**. Like I have specified in this example ImageView.

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/your_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

This will make your application look same on different devices.

Comment: Thanks it really helped me alot